# What format are the images in the delphi IDE menu?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, ota

I'm adding a new entry to the main menu of the Delphi IDE (Delphi 2007) and a bmp image to the image list associated to the menu (without passing a mask as parameter)

```
IDEMainMenu.Images.Add(Image,nil);
```

but the image added is not shown with a transparent color , i tried using a 8 and 24 bits bmp and using fucsia as the background color but the ide always display the icon with the background. so the question is `which is the color depth of the bmp images which i must use and the color of the backgrpund to make appear the image transparent in the delphi ide menu?` or i need pass a mask bmp to the `Images.Add` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using the icon format (.ico) instead, size 16x16 and 256 colors.

this is the code which I use, the `MainMenu` is the instance to the IDE menu item.

```
Image:=TIcon.Create;
try
 Image.Handle := LoadIcon(hInstance, sLogo16);
 ExplorerItem.ImageIndex:=MainMenu.Images.AddIcon(Image);
finally
  Image.Free;
end;
```

[image]